# Dynamic Circular Recycle view List

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, recyclerview-layout, circular-list

I want to create a circular recycle view, where I can populate or change list items on circular motion of my recycle view as shown in the image below. On circular motion the items needs to be changed/replaced as we do in recycle view scroll.

I am unsure about the feasibility for the same, but any help will be appreciated.

[image: CircularRecycleView image]

Comment: I don't think you would be using recyclerview as you won't be recycling any view here

Comment: I think you would most likely have to user a custom view here

Comment: @AceInteract the list items(Sarah, Ethan, Daisy, etc) needs to be recycled on circular motion. How to create a custom view for this?

Comment: https://github.com/Palatis/CircularRecyclerView try it..

Comment: @MonikaMoon Recycling in Android means the adding and removing views only when needed. Like, in normal recyclerview, when a view item has left the screen (that is, has been scrolled past), it is destroyed and then recreated when it enters the screen again (that is, has been scrolled to) so as to save memory and increase app performance. None of the view items you have here will be leaving the screen at any point (at least, from what I understand), so no recycling would be happening

Comment: @MonikaMoon What you need is a custom `LayoutManager`. Check out my answer for better understanding

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to use a custom `LayoutManager` on your `RecyclerView`. Luckily for you, there are a few out there, so you don't have to create yours yourself.

[CircularLayoutManager](https://github.com/kapil93/Circular-Layout-Manager)

[CircleLayoutManager](https://github.com/Lerist/CircleLayoutManager)

[LondonEyeLayoutManager](https://github.com/danylovolokh/LondonEyeLayoutManager)

Simply replace your `GridLayoutManager` or `LinearLayoutManager` with any of these. And you should be good to go

Comment: You can use too this other library https://github.com/leochuan/ViewPagerLayoutManager

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace  the place of Photo  you can make the card view in linearlayout then afte that make the linearlayout height and width match parent the use the gravity to image to replace it